# Have there been any efforts by the countries of Europe to restore their monarchies?

Tags: europe, monarchy, royalty

Have there been any effort, polls, referendum in Europe (especially Eastern ex-communist countries) to restore deposed monarchies, like in Romania, Bulgaria, Serbia, etc.? Most Monarchies were deposed of because of communist regimes, Nazi occupation or military dictatorships rather than the will of the people (correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: On a partly related note, it was once thought that [Karel Schwarzenberg](http://www.economist.com/blogs/easternapproaches/2010/06/karel_schwarzenberg) current [Minister of Foreign Affairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minister_of_Foreign_Affairs_%28Czech_Republic%29) and head of the [House of Schwarzenberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Schwarzenberg) could become elected president of the Czech Republic. It did not happen, and in any case Schwarzenberg is  committed to democracy with solid credentials.

Comment: A surprising related development in the first round of Czech presidential elections is reported [here](http://www.radio.cz/en/section/breaking/milos-zeman-karel-schwarzenberg-heading-to-czech-presidential-runoff-1) ...

Comment: In most most Eastern-European countries the historical monarch houses died out anyway long time ago. Also, in most of these places there were strong revolutionary movements against feudal institutions long before socialism, and monarchy itself is often more of the symbol for these institutions than some kind of national unity.

Comment: Check out Spain. Though it's not simple. Franco more or less assumed the job and they gave it back to the royal family when he died.

Comment: @RedSonja Monarchy in Spain had been in place again since 1946, although the throne remained vacant until Franco died.

Comment: I believe a google search would reveal the answer to this question.

Comment: In asia [Norodom Sihanouk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norodom_Sihanouk) appears to fit your criteria. He abdicated in 1955, became a democratically elected leader, was ousted, and eventually in 1993 he was restored to the monarchy to be succeeded by his son.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, in 1946 the Italians [voted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_constitutional_referendum,_1946) to abolish the kingdom and create the republic, basically because the monarchy was tainted by association with Mussolini. Italy's monarchy was a stronger one (in my estimation) than the East European ones but still it couldn't weather the storm.

I have the impression that in Eastern Europe the real prestige of the monarchies was not very high, the people did not resent them so badly as to oppose them as long as they were in power but on the other hand few cared deeply enough for them to work for their restoration. This might have had a lot to do with the monarchies being mostly young and created by foreign powers. 
You seem to assume otherwise in the question - do you have sources for this assumption?

Comment: My impression is that many countries tried to restore back in many ways of life before the communist rule (language, religion, arts, national identity). The monarchies were of that past and they were deposed by the communists so that they would have served as an icon of restoration. After all, they all assume ceremonial parts.

Answer (score 14):

[Simeon Saxe-Coburg-Gotha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simeon_Saxe-Coburg-Gotha) was  Tsar of Bulgaria from 1943 to 1946. 2001, Simeon resumed the role of leader of the nation upon taking office as Prime Minister of the Republic of Bulgaria from July 2001 until August 2005.

But there were no plans of a [restoration of the Bulgarian monarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simeon_Saxe-Coburg-Gotha#Views_on_restoration_of_the_Bulgarian_monarchy).

Answer (score 13):

There was a [referendum to restore the Albanian monarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albanian_monarchy_referendum,_1997) in 1997, following a period of severe unrest.  The official results of the referendum had the motion failing by a 2-1 margin;  the monarchists then claimed that the result was invalid, riots broke out, and the crown prince Leka fled the country and was tried *in absentia* for inciting rebellion.

The country subsequently adopted a new republican constitution in 1998.  Leka was [later pardoned](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/europe/2072440.stm) and returned to the country, but monarchist ardor seemed to have cooled somewhat:

> Fewer than 500 people turned out to greet him. His supporters had been hoping he would be greeted by a crowd of several thousand.

Leka died in 2011, and it does not appear that [Leka II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leka,_Crown_Prince_of_Albania_(born_1982)) (his son and the current pretender) is currently pressing the monarchist cause:

> After the election of Bujar Nishani as President in 2012, Leka [II] was appointed as political adviser to the President.

Answer (score 10):

Are you restricting your question to a certain time period?  If not, then there are a number of examples, besides those already given in the other answers, which could qualify:

- France has vacillated between a republic and a monarchy several times; the First Republic was succeeded by the First Empire under Napoleon, after which the Bourbon kingdom was restored.  The Second Republic was succeeded by a restoration of the Empire.
- In the 17th century, the three monarchies of England, Scotland, and Ireland (in a personal union) were deposed, and replaced with a unitary republic from 1653 to 1659.  The three monarchies were restored in 1660.
- Spain has also wavered between a republic and a monarchy.  The First Republic was established in 1873, but the Bourbon monarchy was restored the following year.  The Second Republic existed from 1931 to 1939, after which the Bourbon monarchy was again (eventually) restored.

Comment: (+1) The odd thing about France is that the first and second French empires, while clearly autocratic, cannot really be lumped together with the monarchy. To an extent, Napoleon was able to stay in power precisely because he represented an alternative to the Bourbons. But there is another time at which France came very close to a restoration of the monarchy, and that's not 1799, 1804 or 1852 but 1870.

Answer (score 5):

There are a bunch of monarchists in modern Russia. Some are "theoretical" monarchists, some want to bring back Romanovs, some want Putin to be the Tzar.

- [Monarchist party in Russia launched](http://rt.com/politics/monarchist-party-romanov-empire-579/)
- [Wikipedia List of monarchist organizations - Russia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monarchist_organizations_of_the_world#.C2.A0Russia)
- An [article on monarchists in Russia](http://www.rferl.org/content/article/1071729.html):

  > At various times, politicians from across the political spectrum have endorsed constitutional monarchy for Russia, including the former Union of Rightist Forces co-Chairman Boris Nemtsov, Liberal Democratic Party of Russia head Vladimir Zhirinovsky, and St. Petersburg Governor Valentina Matvienko [ *DVK note: For those who don't know Russian politics, these are fairly high level figures in russian politics* ]
  >
  > ... Many intellectuals and cultural icons have also jumped on the monarchy bandwagon. Two of Russia's most popular filmmakers, Nikita Mikhalkov and Stanislav Govorukhin, have paraded their monarchist colors. Stanislav Belkovsky, the founder of the National Strategy Institute, said in February 2005: "I believe that the restoration of the monarchy, either formally or informally, is the only choice for Russia, since it is the only way to restore the sanctity of the supreme power."
  >
  > ...  A September poll by the All-Russia Center for the Study of Public Opinion (VTsIOM) indicated that **19 percent of Russians agreed with restoring the monarchy**, but only if an acceptable candidate can be found. Support is higher in Moscow and St. Petersburg.

The article contains some further info and analysis as well.

Comment: Of course, the people who want Russia to have a Tzar would be the first in line to object to lumping Russia with "Europe", Eastern or otherwise :)

Comment: Actually, having a *constitutional* monarchy on the British model would be the best thing to ever happen to Russia since 1917. Pipe dreams, of course.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg - right, because Russia has a rich tradition of constitutional monarchy....

Comment: @DVK completely unbased statement. Russian monarchy was always German-oriented at least since Peter I, this very much undermined its prestige during WWI because the monarchists often advocated friendship with Germany. Besides this, any political force in Russia associates it with Europe, including the Communists. They very much distinguish between Europe in political and cultural sense and the EU institutions.

Comment: @DVK lol I hope the last statement is sarcasm?

Comment: @Felix Goldberg Russians do not understand why some people have to have more rights because of their birth. They more prefer leaders who originate from the simple people. Regarding British monarchy, arguably it significantly limits the extent of democracy in that country because of potential power and influence of the queen.

Comment: @Anixx - you are confusing 19th century (or 18th) with 21st. The people wishing for monarchy in 21st view Russia NOT as a European country, but as either Asian or "unique" (neither East nor west). But one thing they are not is "zapadniki".

Comment: @Anixx: Re:British Monarchy - this is a ludicrous statement. Re:Russia - This guy makes the case cogently: http://slon.ru/russia/o_svadbe_princa_uilyama_i_neobhodimosti_monarhii_v-587499.xhtml.

Comment: @DVK There are no people who view Russia as "Asian". Yes there are people who view it as "unique". Still do not see any connection to Monarchism.

Comment: @Anixx: Remember how Pushkin once said that the only European in Russia is its government (the English syntax of my translation is garbled as I tried to hew closely to the original)? That's one example for you :) Alexander Bloc is another. I do not take a stand on this, just point out some examples...

Comment: @Felix Goldberg we discussed modern parties as pointed DVK, did not we? Regarding Block, his poem "Scythians" for sure was a metaphor (for example, it is quite known and was known to Block that Slavs had no relation to Scypheans). I do not know what quote from Pushkin are you referring to.

Comment: @Anixx: I just provided some context, if you want modern examples look up the Eurasians (crazy and somewhat dangerous lunatics, imho). Re: metaphor - "Europe" and "Asia" themselves are metaphors, aren't they? They are labels that indicate a certain way of life and a certain philosophical attitude.

Comment: @Felix Goldberg Yes, there are "Eurasians", I never said that they do not exist. I am aware of them.  Eurasians do not counterposit themselves to Europe, they counterposit "Continental", "tellurocratic" culture to "Atlantic", "talassocratic"  culture. This mostly means opposition to the Anglo-Saxons, the US and Britain. They advocate the friendship between the (continental) European peoples (to which they think Russia belongs) and those of Central and East Asia such as China, Iran, Kazakhstan.

Comment: @Anixx - and Eurasians say just what I stated. "Мнение о том, что Россия - азиатская страна, - это мнение сторонников евразийской теории" - http://izvestia.ru/news/301937. Also, [linky](http://forum.cofe.ru/showthread.php?t=135786) and [linky](http://russ.ru/layout/set/print//Mirovaya-povestka/Dyuzhina-nozhej-v-spinu-evrocentrizma)

Comment: @DVK lol you are quoting the opponent of the Eurasians who obviously misinterprets their ideology. He says "they support such and such absurd ideas, but we do not agree on this".

Comment: These nuts are very far from mainstream politics. To say that modern Russians are considering monarchy is like saying that Americans in 1950s were considering communism: just because there a percentage of adherents of either doesn't make them into serious possibilities.

Comment: @Michael - given who's ruling America now (and how), you just delivered the worst possible critique to your own suggestion.

Comment: @DVK: Funny, but politically I disagree. There is far less socialism in USA than in comparably wealthy European countries. As for Russia, the plebs there does indeed have masochistic feeling, the desire to yield all thinking to "the strong hand", and in fact Stalin was a de-facto King of the Realm, but that does not equate to restoration of monarchy.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg There is no good reason whatsoever for any form of monarchy. Unless you're an aristocrat or into being famous in tabloids. Or you know someone who is...

Comment: @jjack - there are plausible arguments that benevolent monarchy is more efficient than other forms (citation: Playing Sid Meyer's Civilization III? :)

Comment: @DVK benevolency generally seems to be a good thing, even for normal people :-)

Comment: Well, how has a republic worked out for Russia so far?

Comment: What do they have right now?

Answer (score 1):

Bavaria stopped being a monarchy not even 100 years ago (1918). After that there were attempts to reinstate the monarchy ([Monarchism in Bavaria after 1918)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monarchism_in_Bavaria_after_1918). Sadly most of these attempts were destroyed by the Nazis (which gives me my very own reason to hate them). If any of these attempts had succeed, maybe WWII could have been delayed and the severity reduced. But it's likely that Adi would have just turned Bavaria into a wasteland.

I'm usually not a monarchist, I think that monarchy is only good if the king is great (which is often not the case). Most of the rulers of Bavaria throughout history were capable leaders who loved their country, not their power. Even today, the official heir of Bavaria would be a great king, which in my opinion is shown even more so because he doesn't want to be king.

Answer (score 1):

**In Romania**, as recent events has shown (during the funerals of HM King Michael I) there is a strong monarchist sentiment among the "profound Romania", the deep, usually silent part of the Romanian populace.

The vast majority of Romanians claim that the Revolution of 1989 is an "unfinished revolution", one that only overthrow Ceaușescu, instead of finishing Communism for good. The obscure and corrupt combination of former politcal police officers and high Communist Party members, now disguised as "investors" and "democratic politicians", is seen as the main reason of the country's mainly negative performance in the last 30 years.

Conversely, the Monarchy (through t**he King's elder daughter, Princess Margareta**) is regarded as the main guarantee for the country's democratic future, stability and conservation of true nation values. So YES, Romanian Monarchy's restoration is possible and very desirable for the political stability of Eastern Europe.

The main reasons why it hasn't happened yet are:

1. an insufficiently informed populace, often a victim of former (42
   years of tough Communism...) and present Leftist propaganda, which
   is still very widespread ("fake news", often gross lies, even in
   mainstream media)
2. former political police officers and other kind of nomenklature
   still controlling all political parties, some NGOs, media outlets
   and the vast part of economic resources
3. insufficient understanding of the "Romanian Royal issue" and support
   for it from the West.

Comment: This well organized answer would be improved with sources/citations that support your points. (I am sure they are available).  Welcome to History.SE. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to see how a Q&A site works differently from a discussion forum.

Answer (score 1):

Big part of the reason of the existence of sovereign states in Eastern Europe is nationalism. However, in many cases these countries did not have own national ruling families. For example Austrian Habsburgs ruled Hungary, Bohemia, Croatia and the territories now known as Slovenia and Slovakia, so most of these countries did not want a foreign monarch back. Poland (and Lithuania) was an elective monarchy before its partition, so there was no real royal house. I don't know if Estonia or Latvia had a royal house at all. Same with Belorussia.